# Why is the conversion between RGB and HLS color systems imprecise?

Tags: python, colors

For one of my applications, I need to convert colors from the RGB to the HLS color system and vice versa. I found that Python has the [colorsys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html) module in its standard library.

The problem is, the conversions are sometimes a bit imprecise and return slightly different results compared to [this online color converter](http://www.workwithcolor.com/color-converter-01.htm).

Here is an example, first two small functions I wrote for convenience:

```
from __future__ import division

import colorsys

def convert_rgb_to_hls(r, g, b):
    h, l, s = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(r/255, g/255, b/255)
    return "HLS(" + str(int(round(h * 359))) + ", " + str(int(round(l * 100))) + ", " + str(int(round(s * 100))) + ")"

def convert_hls_to_rgb(h, l, s):
    r, g, b = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h/359, l/100, s/100)
    return "RGB(" + str(int(round(r * 255))) + ", " + str(int(round(g * 255))) + ", " + str(int(round(b * 255))) + ")"
```

According to the online color converter, RGB(123, 243, 61) should be equal to HLS(100, 60, 88). The results I get using the colorsys functions are different:

```
>>> convert_rgb_to_hls(123, 243, 61)
'HLS(99, 59, 88)'   # should be HLS(100, 60, 88)

>>> convert_hls_to_rgb(100, 60, 88)
'RGB(122, 243, 63)' # should be RGB(123, 243, 61)
```

My first impression was that this is simply a rounding problem, but looking at the difference between 61 and 63, there seems to be another reason. But what is it? Is it possible at all to guarantee an absolute precise conversion between color systems?

Comment: What makes you think that web page is more accurate?

Comment: You are using python 3 or `from __future__ import division`, right?

Comment: Different color spaces have different [gamuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamut) - therefore a lossless conversion is often not possible.

Comment: Integer division would produce the same call for all expected values of `r`, `g`, and `b`: `colorsys.rgb_to_hls(0,0,0)`.

Comment: @chepner That's why I guessed he must be using python 3 or `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: HLS was never designed to be precise. It was designed to be a more intuitive method for humans to specify colors.

Comment: @M4rtini Well, I just assumed that for no particular reason. I know, that's not a good reason but there are not so many color converters on the web where you compare results.

Comment: @pemistahl [hsl-rgb](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsl-to-rgb.htm) [rgb-hsl](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsl.htm) give the results in float, so it might be better for comparison. Altough i do not know if it's more accurate.

Answer (score 4):

```
from __future__ import division

import colorsys

def convert_rgb_to_hls(r, g, b):
    h, l, s = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(r/255, g/255, b/255)
    return "HLS(" + str(int(round(h * 360))) + ", " + str(int(round(l * 100))) + ", " + str(int(round(s * 100))) + ")"

def convert_hls_to_rgb(h, l, s):
    r, g, b = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h/360, l/100, s/100)
    return "RGB(" + str(int(round(r * 255))) + ", " + str(int(round(g * 255))) + ", " + str(int(round(b * 255))) + ")"
```

**Changes**:

- 360 instead of 359 because the range is [0, 360) ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Hue_and_chroma)).
- There were two roundings missing on `convert_rgb_to_hls(r, g, b)`.
- Added python 3 division in case you use python 2.

**Tests**:

```
>>> convert_rgb_to_hls(123, 243, 61)    
'HLS(100, 60, 88)'

>>> convert_hls_to_rgb(100, 60, 88)
'RGB(123, 243, 63)'
```

You were right when you said there were rounding-like errors but the difference between 61 and 63 is because you lose precision when rounding. Do not round for better precision:

```
>>> (r_orig, g_orig, b_orig) = (123, 243, 61)
>>> h,l,s = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(r_orig/255, g_orig/255, b_orig/255)
>>> r, g, b = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h, l, s)
>>> r*255, g*255, b*255
(123.00000000000003, 242.99999999999997, 61.000000000000036)
```

Comment: In Python 2 it's possible to get the desired results from division simply by making the divisors floating point numbers, i.e. `rgb_to_hls(r/255., g/255., b/255.)`, etc. This will continue to work in Python 3, too. Regardless: +1

Comment: Yes, that's another option but I always found the .0 trick less clean. I like Python 3 division, but it may be a matter of taste.

Comment: @DiegoHerranz 

Ok, I see. Obviously, I have to live with losing precision if I want to have an integer representation of the conversion results.

Why do you use 360 instead of 359 for the hue? If you want to represent the hue angles 0-359 degrees by fractions between 0 and 1, 359 would correspond to 1. But that doesn't work if you divide 359 by 360. If you were right, why would you then divide the separate RGB values by 255 and not by 256 (since you have the value range 0-255 = 256 different values)?

Comment: You have to use the maximum value. When using 8 bits (0-255) the maximum value is 255. For hue, the range is [0,360) so the maximum value is not 359 but 359.99999999999999... i.e. 360.

Comment: @DiegoHerranz Ah, I see. That's what I was missing. Thank you. :-)